# Unity - Adressable - Build size is bigger than expected

Tags: unity, assetbundle, addressable

After fixing all duplicates using Analyze tool, the apk file still bigger than before i start using Addressable.

All my bundle is local and use LZ4 compression.

Here what i have done:

- Fix all duplicates found in "Check Duplicate Bundle Dependencies" by moving duplicate assets to appropriate groups.
- Fix all duplicates found in "Check Scene to Addressable Duplicate Dependencies".
- Fix all "Implicit" found in "Bundle Group Preview".

I use this [Build Report Tool](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/build-report-tool-8162?_ga=2.223610075.1347221520.1603076001-1797172034.1600144412#description) and see that non-addressable assets, scripts, dll is about 32MB and aa folder is around 110MB (i have nothing else in StreamingAssets folder) => the apk size should be around 140 - 150 MB but the apk size is 40MB bigger (188MB) :eek:

I suspect there're problem with compression. But have no idea how to fix this.
I extracted the apk and the total size is around 300MB. The non-addressable apk (~150MB)'s extracted size is ~500MB.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. People will start throwing wild guesses, so wait for better answers/comments, but without having worked in your project with you I don't see how to help. Maybe one of those wild guesses save the day for you. Here's mine: suspect compression and try to fix it won't do any good. What's the size of APK without assets, or with the minimal ones for user interface? It's very probably you will have to download assets after game first run, you don't have to control a server for this, [Google offers a solution](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-unity).

Comment: More: advantage of owning a server is that you don't depend on Google services, and your apk can be in any store or in no store. You just have to do web requests. But... owning a server is expensive, just let Google handle it.